# Not able to install/compile rtmp module for nginx using Homebrew

Tags: nginx, homebrew, rtmp

```
>brew install nginx-full --with-rtmp-module
Warning: homebrew/nginx/nginx-full-1.8.0 already installed
```

I already have installed nginx-full and I want to use **rtmp module** for streaming of videos. But I am not able to install it.

Does this mean that this module is already installed? I also ran

`brew options nginx-full`

which tells which tells what are the configuration options available **(not sure)**. It showed around 30-40 modules including the rtmp. Does this mean rtmp module for nginx is already present.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, what you need to do is: reinstall Nginx with append options:

```
brew update
brew reinstall nginx-full --with-rtmp-module
```

This will result in having Nginx with the RTMP module.